# Time and conditional formatting

Tags: excel, time, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditional format a cell with Time in it, so that when the time is 30 minutes before Due the cell will change colour

Scheduled
Departure
Time
| ------- |
| 14:30   |

The cell would change to a red colour when it is 14:00, 30 minutes before the 14:30 scheduled departure time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbkLP.jpg)

I have tried using a =Now()-Time(0,30,) within conditional formatting formula section

Error Message 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmF9b.jpg)

Error Message 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie0Y6.jpg)

I have seen other formulas that use an =IF beforehand

would this make the equation work

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` delievers a Time + Date, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to a Time-Only.

SO you have to use this formular

```
=TIME(HOUR(NOW());MINUTE(NOW())+30;SECOND(NOW())) > A1
```

Comment: I just updated the Formular. I forgot the 30min before. Now it works 100%

Comment: I tried that formula and got 2 different error messages

Comment: What error-messages did you get? You may have to replace the ";" with "," depending on your Excel-Setup. So try using: =TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW())+30,SECOND(NOW())) > A1

Comment: I have attached 2 images of the errors that I was getting - but I will also try your suggest of replacing the ";" with "," and see if that works - Thank You

Comment: I have changed the “;” for “,” as you suggested and I am not getting an error message now. But the conditional formatting is still not working